# Hyperjaxb apply transient dynamically

Tags: transient, hyperjaxb

Currently, I can instruct Hyberjaxb to not persist a node in a xml object at compile time using the transient functionality. Is there anyway of applying this dynamically at runtime? If `x=y`, then persist particular node in xml object, otherwise do not persist.

Is there perhaps another strategy to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a task for Hyperjaxb, since HJ is primarily a compile-time tool. There's a very limited runtime impact only.

Would it be enought to make a deep-copy of the object structure and then remove what you dont' want to be marshalled? You can use something like [copyable plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Copyable+plugin) to generate nice copy/clone methods or even use a custom copy strategy.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to force a compile tool to make runtime decisions, which is not its intended purpose. Thanks.